# Call one query with different parameters using react-query useInfiniteQuery

Tags: react-native, react-query

I have 2 lists that for both of them I should use one query(using useInfiniteQuery). the difference is in a boolean passed parameter.
I don't know how to do this. I tried to call query 2 times in one screen. One time with true parameter value. and another time with false value. Is there any other solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom hook and add that boolean parameter to the QueryKey, as it's a dependency for your query function.